# R - plotting some functions of derivative approximation and integration

Tags: r

I have the following code in R:

```
library(numDeriv)
    
fun1 <- function(x, y) {
      fun2 <- function(x, y) {
        fun2_output <- dlnorm(x, 2.72 - y, 0.52)
        return(fun2_output)
      }
      fun3 <- function(y) {
        fun3_output <- grad(fun2, y)
        return(fun3_output)
      }
      fun1_output <- integrate(fun3, lower = 0, upper = Inf, y = y)$value
      return(fun1_output)
    }
```

So, I have a slightly modified `dlnorm` function which takes `x` and `y` as arguments. Then I want to calculate the derivative of this function with respect to `y`. I am approximating the derivative with numerical differentiation. Then I want to calculate the integral of these derivatives with respect to `x`.

Then I want to create a plots where on the horizontal axis I have `y`, and on the vertical axis I have the value of this integral. I am trying to do it like so:

```
itcc <- Vectorize(itcc)

ggplot() + 
  geom_function(fun = itcc) + 
  xlim(-5, 5)
```

However, it doesn't work because:

```
Warning message:
Computation failed in `stat_function()`
Caused by error in `f()`:
! unused argument (x)
```

Because the notation and the whole procedure could be a bit confusing, I would like to again emphasize just to make sure everyone is on the same page:

1. Derivation is done with respect to **y**
2. Integration is done with respect to **x**
3. Plot is made with **y** on the horizontal axis (x-axis)

What am I doing wrong and how can I make this work?

Comment: What is `itcc`?